# How do I delete my clash of clans village off of my android device?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How do I delete my Clash of Clans village off of my device and delete it from my Google+ account? I do not have access to the original phone that I downloaded it on. I have also disconnected Clash of Clans from Google+ multiple times and then uninstalled the game from my phone. I then re-downloaded but it still has the same village as it did before. It does this even if it is not connected to my Google+.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. Are you trying to delete the village from a device you no longer have, e.g. to prevent someone who has your old device from playing your village? If so, the easiest way is to change your Google+ password. The old device will then require the user to supply a password he doesn't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, you cannot take a village off of a device unless you replace it with another village that is on a different google+ account. The only way for you to access a new Clash of Clans is to have another device and google+ account. So, you cannot remove a village from an account but your can transfer it away from a device.

Comment: there is a way check the other awnser

Comment: @codermaster you can also test my answer...

Comment: It's not true , the other awnsers work as well so your awnser is kind of a lie because ir sais its the only way, which it is not. mark what words you use and if what they mean is true or not.

Answer (score 2):

1. Log off/disconnect from Google+ in Class of Clans.
2. Hold the app, and pull it to the "app info" thing.
3. Click "clear data/cache" (the one next to uninstall app)

Comment: This works if you have the device. The original request seems to be asking how to delete from a device he no longer has access to.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is just simply delete your profile of google play and then again connect to google play in clash of clans and its done your data is saved, no need to create new account.

Comment: This works only if you have the device. The request was to delete from a device he doesn't have.